# Get input value and pass it to route in same blade file Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel

I want to pass selected value from dropdown to be passed throw routing from the same blade file

Here is my blade code :

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label>@lang('site.son')</label>

    @if(Auth::user()->shortsign == '--')
    <select class="select2-size-lg form-control border-primary" style="width: 100%;" name="sign">
        @foreach ($users as $user)
        <option value="{{ $user->shortsign }}">{{ $user->shortsign }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    @else
    <select class="select2-size-lg form-control border-primary" style="width: 100%;" name="sign" readonly>
        <option value="{{ Auth::user()->shortsign }}">{{ Auth::user()->shortsign }}</option>
    </select>
    @endif

</div>

<div class="form-actions right">
    <a href="{{  url('/salereports/report/' . $user->shortsign) }}" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-min-width box-shadow-2 mr-1 mb-1"><i class="la la-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> @lang('site.search')</a>
</div>
```

Now the code iam using pass the last value from database not selected value

Comment: Since you're using `$user->shortsign` after the `@foreach($users as $user)` loop, that value that will equate to is the value that `$user` is after the last iteration. Beyond that, you're gonna need some Javascript to set the value into the `href`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this by giving id to your anchor tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('.select2-size-lg').change(function () {
    var id = $(this).val(); 
    document.getElementById("abc").href="{{  url('/salereports/report/' . id) }}";
});
</script>
```

Comment: i got error ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\orbitgit\resources\views\salereports\index.blade.php)
Previous exceptions
Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (0)

Comment: try by adding + sign before id instead of dot

Comment: I think you should go simply like this document.getElementById("abc").href="'/salereports/report/' . id"